# elasticsearch mapperParsingException on bulk import

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm getting a `MapperParsingException` while trying to upload a large json file. Here is the full error that I get back from elasticsearch:

```
on [[sample][4]]
MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[Malformed content, found extra data after parsing: START_OBJECT];
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:156)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:309)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareCreate(IndexShard.java:529)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareCreateOnPrimary(IndexShard.java:506)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.prepareIndexOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:214)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.executeIndexRequestOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:223)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:157)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryPhase.doRun(TransportReplicationAction.java:657)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:287)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportReplicationAction$PrimaryOperationTransportHandler.messageReceived(TransportReplicationAction.java:279)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:77)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$4.doRun(TransportService.java:376)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed content, found extra data after parsing: START_OBJECT
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:141)
    ... 17 more
```

I'm trying to better understand why exactly the data Im trying to feed in is malformed, and what could I do to better debug this situation?

**EDIT** This is a massive document with 200 million examples, but here is an example data point
`{"company":"E-Corp","title":"Sith lord","people":[{"id":"12345","name":"Darth Vader","title":"The Sith Lord"}]}`

Comment: Could you get us some more information.. A Snippet from the JSON would be useful.

Comment: @SimonLudwig This file has 200 million entries, and not all the entries have all the data filled out, I can show a few examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure every Odd Row is the unique id row:

```
{ "index": {}}
```

And that every Even row is the data:

```
{ "index": {}}
{"company":"E-Corp","title":"Sith lord","people":[{"id":"12345","name":"Darth Vader","title":"The Sith Lord"}]}
```

And to use `_bulk`, so when adding to Elastic:

```
POST /index/type/_bulk
{ "index": {}}
{"company":"E-Corp","title":"Sith lord","people":[{"id":"12345","name":"Darth Vader","title":"The Sith Lord"}]}
{ "index": {}}
{"company":"E-Corp","title":"Sith lord","people":[{"id":"12345","name":"Darth Vader","title":"The Sith Lord"}]}
{ "index": {}}
{"company":"E-Corp","title":"Sith lord","people":[{"id":"12345","name":"Darth Vader","title":"The Sith Lord"}]}
```

Just guessing, cause of the error message: `, found extra data after parsing: START_OBJECT` from your log.

Comment: Yes, that is the error message. Here is how my index looks like `localhost:9200/sample` would that mean that my curl statement looks like `curl -XPOST localhost:9200/sample/_bulk --binary-data @output.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you specifying a mapping? 
If you are not, then elasticsearch will create a mapping based on the first document. Now if any of the other documents have values which do not map to these particular fields, you might get an error.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html

For example, `company` is probably going to be mapped as string, but if a document comes along with a number or date in that field, then an error might be thrown.

You also have nested documents (people) - I would look into that also. Can you try taking a few sample documents - say first 10, and see if you can index them using bulk api.

Or you can create your own mapping for each of these fields, since you do not seem to have a lot of fields per document.

Answer (score 0):

You can have this error

> "Malformed content, found extra data after parsing: START_OBJECT"  }"
>   sent back by ElasticSearch in case your url didn't contain /_bulk at
>   the end.

ElasticSearch is then not expecting to find linefeed and extra data after the last correctly closed curly bracket and discards the extra data 
In particular when issuing a call thru curl namely if you use

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, str)
```

str should be well formed example str shoul be equal to 
'http://localhost:9200/_bulk' and not 'http://localhost:9200'